# Recommended way to get npm-prefix from a node.js script

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

What is the recommended way to get the [npm-prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix) from a node program? The equivalent of `npm prefix -g`

I have a script that uses node.js [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to execute `npm prefix -g` and returns the prefix programmatically. But, this takes more time compared to executing the same in the command line.

There are some npm packages like [global-prefix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-prefix) for finding the npm global prefix. I am looking for an efficient cross platform solution for retrieving the npm global prefix.

Comment: There's no recommended way. Do whatever works for you. Since there are third-party packages, it makes sense to use them instead of reinventing the wheel. *I am looking for an efficient cross platform solution for retrieving the npm global prefix* - what problems did you have with global-prefix? If you didn't, why the question?

Comment: `global-prefix` did not produce consistent results in windows OS. `npm prefix -g` under node child_process is consistent, but it takes few seconds. `npm prefix -g` on the command line is almost instant.

Comment: Was it your own experience or did you check repo issues? global-prefix is widely used and is quite reilable. The only way that is 100% compatible with `npm prefix -g` is `npm prefix -g`. *it takes few seconds. npm prefix -g* - seems unlikely. Just checked it on local system, and it's 0.5s, same duration as CLI.

Comment: Thanks for testing this. There are still open [issues](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/global-prefix/issues) in the `global-prefix` repo. This performance issue is happening mostly in Windows OS running on virtual machines.